# How can input transition timestamp to ffmpeg output file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp, position, transition

I studying about ffmpeg and I did extraction scene transition from video files using the follows command.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -i inputfile.mp4 -vf select="gt(scene\, 0.5), scale="640:360" -vsync vfr -frames:v 100 output.png
```

I was able to get hundreds of scene transition files.

I have a question in here.

I want know play time when I extraction scene transition.

Anything is gonna be okay, make the filename using play time or anything is ok.

ex) 00:06:13.png 00:09:12.png ... 01:12:01.png

Comment: Can you make more clear what your question is?

Comment: Sorry my English skills.. :( I generated 100 png files (scene transition of video). 1.png, 2.png ... 100.png. I want know all of files play time point of video. For example) 1.png file time is 00:05:01 from video play time. 2.png file time is 00:09:38 from video play time.

Comment: This was just that someone else can answer. I'm not able. You could update (edit) your post so that the problem/question is more understandable. Otherwise you might not get any reply...